# Logo import into antenna photo

Tags: adobe-photoshop, smartobject, perspective

I photographed antenna a lot of diffrent perspective like this and i have to add company logo into all antena bowl.

I wonder that can i creat a smart object like antena bowl to add logo into the antena bowl to creat perfect perspective.

https://i.hizliresim.com/XP6W90.jpg
https://i.hizliresim.com/QV2Xvv.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can.

Apply an *Edit > Transform > Warp*, to a Smart Object. In the example below, I have a simple logo on a white background, converted to a Smart Object, and the layer mode set to multiply.

When added to a Smart Object, Photoshop remembers the Warp mesh, and it can be adjusted at any time. You can also use the Perspective, and Distort transforms in the same way.

[image]